# Using PrinterFiscalClass in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, ocx, epson

How can I use the class `EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal.PrinterFiscal` from Epson OCX in C#?

Currently, I'm traying to do this:

```
EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal.PrinterFiscal printerfiscal1 = new EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal.PrinterFiscal();
printerfiscal1.FeedPaper("A", "5");
```

But I'm getting the following error in compile time:

> The type 'EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal.PrinterFiscalClass' has no constructors defined

Comment: [This error occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6fxc01.aspx) if the class only defines an internal constructor and you try to instantiate it from another assembly.  Do you have an API reference for the Epson library?  `EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal` doesn't seem to Google.

Comment: Which API reference? I have the OCX file, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Use a typelib browser, and look for functions (methods) which return an object of that kind.

Comment: Hi @Faabass ! Where can I get the EPSON_Impresora_Fiscal DLL ? Thanks!